# Razor View must derive WebPageView but I have a reference to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mef

This is my razor view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

<h2>Index</h2>
```

It recognizes `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` but when I try to run it from my main app, it says the view must derive from WebViewPage.

Comment: It asks for a WebViewPage. I have it as an embedded resource but it also asks for the same thing if I make the razor view content.

Comment: are you trying to make:
@RenderPage("view") or Html.Partial, etc from a .cshtml page to a view in a non "standard MVC" directory? Tx